# Spring boot on Heroku doesn't register requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js

My front-end is a Nuxt App and API is Spring boot. In my local development environment everthying works fine. However after hosting both applications on Heroku, couple of URLs are returning 404 pages. 
In Heroku logs for my API, I noticed that when I click on admin/tours or admin/bikes page they should fetch data from /tours and /bikes endpoints but it never registers the path.

[image: Path is never being hit]

[image: hitting admin/tours return 404 and console is empty]

First I thought, it was a problem with my front end code. But routes are working fine in local environment. 
Then I thought it was something with API. But when I manually hit the hosted API route on browser it is working fine too.
Building the app and running on production mode in local machine also working fine.

[image: manually hitting the endpoint is working]

I can't figure out why It never hits those two routes but others.

Comment: This looks like an application problem to me. If other routes are working fine your setup for Heroku should be good, especially when you can access the APIs on Heroku with a browser without a problem. I suggest looking at outbound XHR requests on the 404-ing site in your browser to see what's going on.

Comment: I checked and XHR requests are not being made on hosted app for those two routes. Any particular reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. 
I have pages in `pages` directory called `bikes` and `tours`.
I also have pages in `pages/admin` directory called `bikes` and `tours`.
Even though technically my routes are fine, when building on Heroku it renames `index.vue` files inside `admin` directory to `Index.vue` to differentiate the pages.

[image]

The **fix** is to rename pages in one of the directories or name the pages differently by passing a `name` option inside pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the 'Procfile' to the root of your Spring Boot application?
I ran into a similar issue last year and I added a 'Procfile' (with no extension) to the root of my Spring Boot app and it solved it.

Add this line to your 'Procfile'

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
```

More information here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#default-web-process-type

Comment: If I do this, does that mean I have to deploy a .jar file?